# Lua: load one function from large library

Tags: lua

I have a lua library QL.lua with many functions. I want only some of them. How can I load them? I want something like pythons option

```
from socket import timeout
```

I tried in lua

```
local f = package.loadlib("C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/QL.lua", "math_round")
```

But it doesn't work for me

Comment: [QL.lua](https://github.com/ahmpro/qllib/blob/master/QL.lua) is not a "proper" Lua library, it is just a Lua script which creates many global functions.  So, the only way to get a single function is to run `QL.lua` as a whole and get all the functions.